# Why does Al Chet not have the definite article, i.e., Al HAchet?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, yom-kippur, viduy-confession

Since the phrase is translated, "for the sin," and it isn't smichut, why is there no definite article?

Comment: I believe that the *the* is only because of English usage. In the Hebrew usage it would be *any sin of the type ...*

Comment: To add on to the above, once it says hachet, that would imply one specific sin only, not all sins of thay type.

Comment: Hmm, maybe? But doesn't shechatanu lefaneikha imply definition? I can't quite imagine how to translate it, without: for a sin that we sinned before you? for any sin that we sinned before you?